# saving data points coordinates in database

Tags: php, database

Would you save each point (x/y) as one entry or would you dump the list of data points in a varchar? I can't decide what would be best, eventually I'll need to get the data out to graph it, if it's one point per entry I can do a group_concat when returning the data while if it's in a big varchar I can explode it in php on the server.

I'm sure it might be obvious with the minimal of experience however I have none in this area.

Comment: I would store them seperately for the flexibility of being able to sort, order etc at the database itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to process them, for example if its geographical data and you want to find nearest point, then obviously yes, save as separate values. And if its DB that supports quick processing [like mongo](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Geospatial+Indexing) does, then definitely.